# horizontal and vertical Headers in long table

Tags: header-footer, longtable

this is the output of my Stata code. I have two main problems with my table. First, I want to  include horizontal vertical headers like in the desired picture and second, I want to fit my long table with the paper margins

my code :

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        hmargin=15mm, vmargin={1cm,2cm}]{geometry}
 \usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage[hang, font=small, 
        labelfont=bf,textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
 \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}



\begin{document}


 \begin{table}[htbp]\centering
 \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Table4\_PUSH\_PULL\_FACTORS\_FULL\_CONTROLS}
\begin{tabular}{l*{12}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}         \\
\hline

ONE BELT, ONE ROAD POSITION&    0.819\sym{*}  &    0.528         &    1.025\sym{*}  &    0.466         &    0.305         &    0.349         &    0.804\sym{***}&    0.699\sym{**} &    0.627         &    0.680\sym{**} &    0.574\sym{*}  &    0.644\sym{**} \\
            &   (1.95)         &   (1.32)         &   (1.85)         &   (1.19)         &   (0.82)         &   (0.93)         &   (2.66)         &   (2.38)         &   (1.62)         &   (2.33)         &   (1.94)         &   (2.15)         \\
[1em]
FTA WITH CHINA  &    0.379         &    0.434         &   -0.256         &    0.387         &    0.470         &    0.395         &    0.491         &    0.536\sym{*}  &    0.127         &    0.499         &    0.514\sym{*}  &    0.514\sym{*}  \\
            &   (0.98)         &   (1.18)         &  (-0.48)         &   (1.04)         &   (1.24)         &   (1.09)         &   (1.61)         &   (1.70)         &   (0.33)         &   (1.62)         &   (1.78)         &   (1.71)         \\
[1em]
BIT WITH CHINA  &    1.061\sym{**} &    1.140\sym{***}&    0.000         &    1.189\sym{***}&    1.183\sym{***}&    1.138\sym{***}&    0.918\sym{***}&    0.957\sym{***}&    1.691\sym{***}&    0.980\sym{***}&    0.997\sym{***}&    0.953\sym{***}\\
            &   (2.49)         &   (2.72)         &      (.)         &   (2.84)         &   (2.98)         &   (2.88)         &   (2.88)         &   (3.03)         &   (3.58)         &   (3.20)         &   (3.29)         &   (3.19)         \\
[1em]
FINANCIAL CRISES&    0.087\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.050\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
            &   (3.54)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (2.67)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
 [1em]
IDEAL POINT DISTANCE FROM CHINA&   -0.616\sym{*}  &   -0.419         &   -0.735\sym{*}  &   -0.427         &   -0.363         &   -0.363         &   -0.204         &   -0.162         &   -0.329         &   -0.181         &   -0.178         &   -0.212         \\
            &  (-1.95)         &  (-1.53)         &  (-1.86)         &  (-1.47)         &  (-1.32)         &  (-1.36)         &  (-0.97)         &  (-0.76)         &  (-1.18)         &  (-0.89)         &  (-0.88)         &  (-1.06)         \\
[1em]
 REGIME TYPE     &   -0.016         &    0.013         &    0.131\sym{**} &    0.008         &    0.027         &    0.023         &   -0.008         &    0.006         &    0.030         &   -0.000         &    0.017         &    0.014         \\
            &  (-0.49)         &   (0.46)         &   (2.30)         &   (0.28)         &   (0.97)         &   (0.80)         &  (-0.28)         &   (0.25)         &   (0.71)         &  (-0.00)         &   (0.65)         &   (0.55)         \\
 [1em]
 LEADER IDEOLOGY &   -0.127         &   -0.098         &   -0.009         &   -0.025         &   -0.073         &   -0.072         &   -0.121         &   -0.110         &   -0.153         &   -0.087         &   -0.117         &   -0.112         \\
            &  (-1.06)         &  (-0.88)         &  (-0.05)         &  (-0.22)         &  (-0.69)         &  (-0.68)         &  (-1.26)         &  (-1.15)         &  (-1.06)         &  (-0.90)         &  (-1.24)         &  (-1.19)         \\
[1em]
AFRICA DUMMY    &   -1.140\sym{**} &   -0.965\sym{*}  &    0.000         &   -0.886\sym{*}  &   -1.061\sym{**} &   -1.023\sym{**} &   -0.893\sym{**} &   -0.827\sym{**} &   -1.426\sym{**} &   -0.791\sym{*}  &   -0.979\sym{**} &   -0.918\sym{**} \\
            &  (-2.10)         &  (-1.89)         &      (.)         &  (-1.69)         &  (-2.13)         &  (-2.05)         &  (-2.26)         &  (-2.05)         &  (-2.33)         &  (-1.94)         &  (-2.50)         &  (-2.34)         \\
 [1em]
 GDP GROWTH      &    0.013         &    0.001         &   -0.049         &    0.010         &    0.008         &    0.007         &   -0.000         &   -0.007         &   -0.015         &   -0.001         &   -0.001         &   -0.001         \\
            &   (0.57)         &   (0.04)         &  (-1.40)         &   (0.45)         &   (0.35)         &   (0.32)         &  (-0.01)         &  (-0.37)         &  (-0.63)         &  (-0.09)         &  (-0.07)         &  (-0.08)         \\
 [1em]
GDP             &   -0.000         &    0.000\sym{**} &   -0.000         &    0.000         &    0.000\sym{*}  &    0.000         &   -0.000         &    0.000         &   -0.000         &    0.000         &    0.000         &    0.000         \\
            &  (-0.10)         &   (2.30)         &  (-0.49)         &   (1.27)         &   (1.65)         &   (0.48)         &  (-0.29)         &   (0.62)         &  (-0.14)         &   (0.27)         &   (0.31)         &   (0.40)         \\
  [1em]
   LOG GDPPC       &   -0.201         &   -0.228\sym{*}  &    0.269         &   -0.144         &   -0.149         &   -0.178         &   -0.057         &   -0.005         &    0.134         &    0.021         &    0.005         &   -0.030         \\
            &  (-1.13)         &  (-1.66)         &   (1.13)         &  (-1.02)         &  (-1.08)         &  (-1.29)         &  (-0.43)         &  (-0.04)         &   (0.69)         &   (0.17)         &   (0.05)         &  (-0.25)         \\
[1em]
 CIRI HUMAN RIGHTS INDEX&    0.105         &   -0.019         &   -0.317\sym{**} &    0.006         &   -0.080         &   -0.066         &    0.023         &   -0.042         &   -0.126         &   -0.011         &   -0.085         &   -0.072         \\
            &   (0.81)         &  (-0.19)         &  (-2.18)         &   (0.06)         &  (-0.89)         &  (-0.72)         &   (0.27)         &  (-0.56)         &  (-1.08)         &  (-0.14)         &  (-1.20)         &  (-1.01)         \\
[1em]
 VARIABILITY OF CAPITAL ACCOUNT POLICY&                  &    3.567\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    2.567\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  \\
            &                  &   (2.71)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (2.82)         &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
  [1em]
  VOLATILITY OF PORTFOLIO OUTFLOWS&                  &                  &    0.367\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.234         &                  &                  &                  \\
            &                  &                  &   (2.73)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (1.62)         &                  &                  &                  \\
[1em]
 SOCIAL UNREST DURING IMF PROGRAMS&                  &                  &                  &    0.011\sym{**} &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.011\sym{**} &                  &                  \\
            &                  &                  &                  &   (2.02)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (2.39)         &                  &                  \\
 [1em]
 WTO COMPLAINTS AGAINST THE U.S.&                  &                  &                  &                  &   -0.064         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   -0.034         &                  \\
            &                  &                  &                  &                  &  (-0.93)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &  (-0.70)         &                  \\
[1em]
IMF GOVERNANCE DEFICIT&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.062         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.321         \\
            &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (0.22)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (1.26)         \\
       [1em]
         Constant        &   -0.532         &   -0.164         &   -2.045         &   -0.697         &    0.052         &    0.229         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
            &  (-0.41)         &  (-0.15)         &  (-1.02)         &  (-0.58)         &   (0.05)         &   (0.22)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
          \hline
     /               &                  &                  &                  &                  
 &                  
   &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  
 &                  \\
            cut1            &                  &                  &                  &                  
   &                  &                  &    0.273         &    0.662         &    1.580         
  &    0.828         &    0.106         &   -0.080         \\
              &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  
  &                         &   (0.26)         &   (0.64)         &   (1.01)         &   (0.77)         &   (0.11)         &  (-0.08)         \\
     [1em]
      cut2            &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    1.454         &    1.944\sym{*}  &    2.940\sym{*}  &    2.112\sym{*}  &    1.353         &    1.171         \\
            &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  
  &                  &   (1.39)         &   (1.85)         &   (1.88)         &   (1.95)         &   (1.41)         &   (1.22)         \\
            \hline
            Observations    &      144         &      149         &       63         &      153         &      153         &      151         &      142         &      146         &       82         &      150         &      150         &      148         \\
 Pseudo \(R^{2}\)&    0.346         &    0.299         &    0.244         &    0.293         &    0.268         &    0.260         &    0.259         &    0.260         &    0.215         &    0.262         &    0.244         &    0.243         \\
\hline\hline
  \multicolumn{13}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
  \multicolumn{13}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Desired Tables:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your MWE doesn't contain a `longtable`. BTW, long table had not be enclosed in float environment, your table far to wide that can be fit on (portrait) page ...

Comment: Is table in the  ˙landscape` orientation an option?

Comment: @zarko i would prefer an option to fit the table on one page

Comment: In `landscape`  orientation can be fit in one page ... (hopefully).

Comment: @zarko Please any suggestions to save me :)

Comment: Unfortunately , with readable size of fonts in table, your table cannot be fit in one page. You need to use long table and split over two page.  If this is option, I can provide (already prepared) answer.

Comment: @zarko since it is the only option i would accept it , please provide it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table is to huge that can be fit on one page with readable size of font in table. As solution can be long table in landscape orientation split between two page.

Off-topic:

- by use of `tabularray` (which you already loaded) the table code is simpler
- I would use `S` column type (defined in `siunitx` package loaded by TblrLibrary of the same name) for columns with numbers,

**Edit (1):**

- to make text in the first column more narrow and that it be in cells split in the most in two lines, I would change fonts in this column to `\scshape`.
- in the first column cells where the text split into two lines I would manually set multi row cells by use `\SetCell[r=2]{l} text in cell`

**Edit (2):**

- added row for "attendance" and ordered attendance" headers
- added intermediate table headers in shaded rows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        hmargin=15mm, vmargin={1cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {6}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \small
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
    table-align-text-after=false,
    table-align-text-before=false,
    table-format={(}-1.3{**}
        }

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Push and pull factors \dots},
 note{} = {Standard errors in parentheses:\newline
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.},
                ]{
    rowhead= 2,
    colsep = 2pt,
    colspec= {@{} X[l,h, font=\scshape\linespread{0.84}\selectfont]
                  *{12}{S}
              @{}},
    row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
    row{4-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt},
    row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=1ex},
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}
    &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}
        {{{DV= ATTENDANCE (probit)}}}  
        &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}
                                {{{DV = ORDERED ATTENDANCE (ordered probit)}}} % 
                                &   &   &   &   &           \\
    \cmidrule[0.6pt, r]{2-7}
    \cmidrule[0.6pt, l]{8-13}
    &{{{(1)}}}  &{{{(2)}}}  &{{{(3)}}}  &{{{(4)}}}  &{{{(5)}}}  &{{{(6)}}}
    &{{{(7)}}}  &{{{(8)}}}  &{{{(9)}}}  &{{{(10)}}} &{{{(11)}}} &{{{(12)}}} \\
    \midrule
%%%%
\SetCell[c=13]{c, font=\itshape, bg=gray8}    Pull Factors
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &            \\
%%%%
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    One belt, one road position
    & 0.819\TblrNote{*}
            & 0.528 & 1.025\TblrNote{*}
                            & 0.466 & 0.305 & 0.349
    & 0.804\TblrNote{***}
            & 0.699\TblrNote{**}
                    & 0.627 & 0.680\TblrNote{**}
                                    & 0.574\TblrNote{*}
                                            & 0.644\TblrNote{**}    \\
    &(1.95) &(1.32) &(1.85) &(1.19) &(0.82) &(0.93)
    &(2.66) &(2.38) &(1.62) &(2.33) &(1.94) &(2.15)                 \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    FTA with China
    & 0.379 & 0.434 &-0.256 & 0.387 & 0.470 & 0.395
    & 0.491 & 0.536\TblrNote{*}
                    & 0.127 & 0.499 & 0.514\TblrNote{*}
                                            & 0.514\TblrNote{*}     \\
    &(1.95) &(1.32) &(1.85) &(1.19) &(0.82) &(0.93)
    &(2.66) &(2.38) &(1.62) &(2.33) &(1.94) &(2.15)                 \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    BIT with China
    & 1.061\TblrNote{**}
            &1.140\TblrNote{***}
                    & 0.000 & 1.189\TblrNote{***}
                                    & 1.183\TblrNote{***}
                                            & 1.138\TblrNote{***}
    & 0.918\TblrNote{***}
            & 0.957\TblrNote{***}
                    & 1.691\TblrNote{***}
                            & 0.980\TblrNote{***}
                                    & 0.997\TblrNote{***}
                                            & 0.953\TblrNote{***}   \\
    &(2.49) &(2.72) &(0.0)  &(2.84) &(2.98) &(2.88)
    &(2.88) &(3.03) &(3.58) &(3.20) &(3.29) &(3.19)                 \\
%%%%%
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=2,c=13]{c, font=\itshape, bg=gray8}    Push Factors 
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
%%%%%
Financial crises
    & 0.087\TblrNote{***}
            &       &       &       &       &
    & 0.050\TblrNote{***}
            &       &       &       &       &                       \\
    &(3.54) &       &       &       &       &
    &(2.67) &       &       &       &       &                       \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Variability of capital account policy
    &       & 3.567\TblrNote{***}
                    &       &       &       &
    &       & 2.567\TblrNote{***}
                    &       &       &       &                               \\
    &       &(2.71) &       &       &       &
    &       &(2.82) &       &       &       &                               \\
    
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Volatility of portfolio outflows
    &       &       & 0.367\TblrNote{***}
                            &       &       &
    &       &       & 0.234 &       &       &                               \\
    &       &       &(2.73) &       &       &
    &       &       &(1.62) &       &       &                               \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Social unrest during IMF programs
    &       &       &       & 0.011\TblrNote{**}
                                    &       &
    &       &       &       & 0.011\TblrNote{**}
                                    &       &                               \\
    &       &       &       &(2.02) &       &
    &       &       &       &(2.39) &       &                               \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    WTO complaints against the U.S.
    &       &       &       &       &-0.064 &
    &       &       &       &       &-0.034 &                               \\
    &       &       &       &       &(-0.93)&
    &       &       &       &       &(-0.70)&                               \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    IMF governance deficit
    &       &       &       &       &       & 0.062
    &       &       &       &       &       & 0.321                         \\
    &       &       &       &       &       &(0.22)
    &       &       &       &       &       &(1.26)                         \\
%%%%%
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=13]{c, font=\itshape, bg=gray8}    Controls
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
%%%%%
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Ideal point distance from China
    & -0.616\TblrNote{*}
            &-0.419 & -0.735\TblrNote{*}
                            &-0.427 &-0.363 &-0.363
    &-0.204 &-0.162 &-0.329 &-0.181 &-0.178 &-0.212                 \\
    &(-1.95)&(-1.53)&(-1.86)&(-1.47)&(-1.32)&(-1.36)
    &(-0.97)&(-0.76)&(-1.18)&(-0.89)&(-0.88)&(-1.06)                \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Regime type
    &-0.016 & 0.013 & 0.131\TblrNote{**}
                            & 0.008 & 0.027 & 0.023
    &-0.008 & 0.006 & 0.030 &-0.000 & 0.017 & 0.014                 \\
    &(-0.49)&(0.46) &(2.30) &(0.28) &(0.97) &(0.80)
    &(-0.28)&(0.25) &(0.71) &(-0.00)&(0.65) &(0.55)                 \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Leader ideology
    &-0.127 &-0.098 &-0.009 &-0.025 &-0.073 &-0.072
    &-0.121 &-0.110 &-0.153 &-0.087 &-0.117 &-0.112                 \\
    &(-1.06)&(-0.88)&(-0.05)&(-0.22)&(-0.69)&(-0.68)
    &(-1.26)&(-1.15)&(-1.06)&(-0.90)&(-1.24)&(-1.19)                \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Africa dummy
    & -1.140\TblrNote{**}
            & -0.965\TblrNote{*}
                    & 0.000 & -0.886\TblrNote{*}
                                    & -1.061\TblrNote{**}
                                            & -1.023\TblrNote{**}
    & -0.893\TblrNote{**}
            & -0.827\TblrNote{**}
                    & -1.426\TblrNote{**}
                            & -0.791\TblrNote{*}
                                    & -0.979\TblrNote{**}
                                            & -0.918\TblrNote{**}   \\
    &(-2.10)&(-1.89)& (.)   &(-1.69)&(-2.13)&(-2.05)
    &(-2.26)&(-2.05)&(-2.33)&(-1.94)&(-2.50)&(-2.34)                \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    GDP growth
    & 0.013 & 0.001 &-0.049 & 0.010 & 0.008 & 0.007
    &-0.000 &-0.007 &-0.015 &-0.001 &-0.001 &-0.001         \\
    &(0.57) &(0.04) &(-1.40)&(0.45) &(0.35) &(0.32)
    &(-0.01)&(-0.37)&(-0.63)&(-0.09)&(-0.07)&(-0.08)        \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    GDP &-0.000 & 0.000\TblrNote{**}
                    &-0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000\TblrNote{*}
                                            & 0.000
    &-0.000 & 0.000 &-0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 &    0.000                      \\
    &(-0.10)&(2.30) &(-0.49)&(1.27) &(1.65) &(0.48)
    &(-0.29)&(0.62) &(-0.14)&(0.27) &(0.31) &(0.40)                         \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    LOG GDPPC
    &-0.201 &-0.228\TblrNote{*}
                    & 0.269 &-0.144 &-0.149 &-0.178
    &-0.057 &-0.005 & 0.134 & 0.021 & 0.005 &-0.030                         \\
    &(-1.13)&(-1.66)&(1.13) &(-1.02)&(-1.08)&(-1.29)
    &(-0.43)&(-0.04)&(0.69) &(0.17) &(0.05) &(-0.25)                        \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Ciri human rights index
    & 0.105 &-0.019 &-0.317\TblrNote{**}
                            & 0.006 &-0.080 &-0.066
    & 0.023 &-0.042 &-0.126 &-0.011 &-0.085 &-0.072                         \\
    &(0.81) &(-0.19)&(-2.18)&(0.06) &(-0.89)&(-0.72)
    &(0.27) &(-0.56)&(-1.08)&(-0.14)&(-1.20)&(-1.01)                        \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Constant
    &-0.532 &-0.164 &-2.045 &-0.697 & 0.052 & 0.229
    &       &       &       &       &       &                               \\
    &(-0.41)&(-0.15)&(-1.02)&(-0.58)&(0.05) & (0.22)
    &       &       &       &       &       &                               \\
    \midrule  
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    cut 1 Constant
    &       &       &       &       &       &
    & 0.273 & 0.662 & 1.580 & 0.828 & 0.106 & -0.080                \\
    &       &       &       &       &       &
    &(0.26) &(0.64) &(1.01) &(0.77) &(0.11) &(-0.08)                \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    cut 2 Constant
    &       &       &       &       &       &
    & 1.454 & 1.944\TblrNote{*}
                    & 2.940\TblrNote{*}
                            & 2.112\TblrNote{*}
                                    & 1.353 & 1.171                 \\
            &                  &                  &                  &                  &
  &                  &   (1.39)         &   (1.85)         &   (1.88)         &   (1.95)         &   (1.41)         &   (1.22)         \\
    \midrule
Observations
    &{{{144}}}  &{{{149}}}  &{{{63}}}  &{{{153}}}  &{{{153}}}  &{{{151}}}
    &{{{142}}}  &{{{146}}}  &{{{82}}}  &{{{150}}}  &{{{150}}}  &{{{148}}}                     \\
Pseudo \(R^{2}\)
    & 0.346 & 0.299 & 0.244 & 0.293 & 0.268 & 0.260
    & 0.259 & 0.260 & 0.215 & 0.262 & 0.244 & 0.243                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: dear friend, is it possible two include headers ( vertical and horizontal)  like the desired picture ??

Comment: @Haithem, very hart, since i don't figured out where should be those headers. However, since there is also problem with width of table, you ma consider add row with this header. BTW, I will change a table a wee bit. See edited answer (will appear ASAP).

Comment: @thanks zarko, I appreciate your guidance

Comment: @Haithem, see second edit. Now is table almost complete. You may liked it. BTW, you can up-vote my answer instead saying "thank you" ;-)

Comment: Very Profesional... Thank you for such a wonderful contribution.